# Globally effect a CSS Class with multiple ID types?

Tags: css

I still in the learning process but I think spending over 5 hours on a problems is sufficient time to start asking questions! Unsure if the post title accurately explains the issue? See the attached image.

Trying to change min-height: 100px (basically get rid of the large gap between questions.

Any changes I make to min-height don't seem to take outside of the inspector. Thoughts?

[Link to image showing the CSS on page](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xbound.io/edit+min-height.png)

[Link to page on site](https://www.xbound.io/discussions/)

[Link to CSS page](https://www.xbound.io/wp-content/plugins/cm-answers-idea-stimulator-addon/asset/css/petition.css)

Thanks to all for assistance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

remove min-height large gap between questions will resolve auto

Answer (score 0):

Please follow advise in comments above. However, you just need to https://www.xbound.io/wp-content/plugins/cm-answers-idea-stimulator-addon/asset/css/petition.css

and comment out the min-height line for

```
.cma-thread-snippet {
    position: relative;
    /* min-height: 250px !important; */
    padding: 20px 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks all for your responses. I feel silly. It wasn't anything I wasn't doing properly, as far the the css goes. Come to find out it was a cache issue because I was using cloudflare! So my changes weren't going live.

This could be helpful to leave up as a lesson to others, haha. Thanks again for you time.